# Php - Display data from sql arranged by date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am kinda off stuck right now, hope that you guys call help me.

I have a tabel in my db that looks like this:

```
Game - kickoff             - result
g1   - 2014-12-23 15:00:00 - 1
g2   - 2014-12-23 15:00:00 - 1
g3   - 2014-12-24 15:00:00 - 1
g4   - 2014-12-24 15:00:00 - 1
g5   - 2014-12-25 15:00:00 - 1
```

And i want to display it in my page so it looks like this:

```
23-12-2014:
G1 - 15:00
G2 - 15:00

24-12-2014
G3 - 15:00
G4 - 15:00

25-12-2014
G5 - 15:00
```

So it is arranged by the dates, and I can figure out how i should do this.

This is where i am, but i dont know how to seperate by dates.

```
$tips = $db -> select("SELECT * FROM games");

foreach($tips as $result) {

$game= $result['game'];
$kickoff= $result['kickoff'];
$result_end= $result['result'];

echo $game . $kickoff . $result_end;
}
```

Comment: It is confusing, please explain in detail.

Comment: I want to display my data as:

kickoff date:
game1
game2

etc. so it would be:

2014-12-23
G1 - 15:00
G2 - 15:00

2014-12-24
G3 - 15:00 etc..

If you look at the database (fist code)

Comment: I have edited the answer, try the code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
$tips = $db->select("SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY kickoff");

$lastkickoffdate = '';
foreach($tips as $result) {

    $game        = $result['game'];
    $kickoff     = $result['kickoff'];
    $kickoffdate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($kickoff));
    $kickofftime = date('H:i', strtotime($kickoff));
    $result_end  = $result['result'];

    if($kickoffdate != $lastkickoffdate){
        echo '<p>'.$kickoffdate.'</p>';
    }
    echo ucfirst($game) .' - '. $kickofftime.'<br>';
    $lastkickoffdate = $kickoffdate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can format the date and time separately so you can display them separately too. 
Then you can keep a variable to check whether the date differs from the previous date.

It is important to sort the query as well (add ORDER BY), otherwise the same date might occur more than once.

This code assumes that `kickoff` is a timestamp. If it's a string you may have to parse it in another way, but that is a specific implementation detail.

```
<?php

$tips = $db -> select("SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY kickoff");

$lastkickoffdate = '';
foreach($tips as $result) {

    $game= $result['game'];
    $kickoff= $result['kickoff'];
    $result_end= $result['result'];

    $kickoffdate = date("Y-m-d", $kickoff);
    $kickofftime = date('H:i', $kickoff);

    if ($kickoffdate !== $lastkickoffdate)
    {
        echo $kickoffdate . '<br>';
    }

    echo "$game - $kickofftime - $result_end";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change

```
$tips = $db -> select("SELECT * FROM games");
```

to

```
$tips = $db -> select("SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY kickoff");
```

Comment: Yes, but then how can i seperate the dates, so i write in php when it is a new date and sort the games beneath :)?